# Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I'm stuck with a problem on my code. The codes is the following:

```
for file in files:
        df=pd.read_csv(file)
        df["time_stamp"]=pd.to_datetime(df["time_stamp"], infer_datetime_format=True)
        df= df.resample('1Min', on='time_stamp').first().dropna()
        df["time_diff"]=df["time_stamp"].diff() 
        df=df[1:]
        df["time_diff_h"]=df["time_diff"].apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds()/3600)
        
        
        df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
        #index_list=df[df["time_diff_h"]>time_gap].index
        index_list = df[df["time_diff_h"]>24].index
        
        if len(index_list)==0:
            continue
        df_output=pd.DataFrame()
        for i in index_list:
            soc_diff=df["ibs3_soc__0x7a3 (%)"].iloc[i]-df["ibs3_soc__0x7a3 (%)"].iloc[i-1]
            initial_soc=df["ibs3_soc__0x7a3 (%)"].iloc[i-1]
            final_soc=df["ibs3_soc__0x7a3 (%)"].iloc[i]
            timeDiff= round((df["time_diff_h"].iloc[i]),2)
            initial_time=df["time_stamp"].iloc[i-1]
            final_time=df["time_stamp"].iloc[i]
            power=(df["ibs3_q_released__0x7a3 (ah)"].iloc[i]-df["ibs3_q_released__0x7a3 (ah)"].iloc[i-1])/timeDiff
           
            if power<0.125:
                continue
            else:
                features={"File": file, "SOC_Difference (%)": soc_diff, "Initial_SOC (%)": initial_soc, "Final_SOC (%)": final_soc, "Time_Diff (h)": timeDiff, "Initial_time": initial_time, "Final_time": final_time, "Power_released (Ah)": power}
            
            df_output=df_output.append(pd.Series(features), ignore_index=True)
```

But it generates this typerror:

```
raise TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}")

TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int
```

But I can't understand why, since I converted the column "time_diff_h" into a float/int using `df.total_seconds` and dividing it by 3600 to obtain the time in hours.

Besides, if I search which dataframe column have a timedelta type using this code:

```
timedelta_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=['timedelta64[ns]']).columns
```

The result is only the column time_diff, but I'm not comparin it to any float variable.
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Does changing `24` to `pd.Timedelta(24,'h')` fix your problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If I run the code, without any modifiction, in debug mode or in the console it works, but when I run the enire code this error appears. If I check the dtype of this time_diff_h column it is already set to float, so I don't understand where the problem is and when and why it is considered of a timedelta type.

Comment: It looks like there is not enough information about the error. Where exactly does it appear and what was the exception stack trace?